# Regex to exclude files in find in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to write a regex to find that excludes files.

I have a structure like

```
.../file1.txt
.../foo/file2.txt
.../fum/file3.txt
```

and I receive a variable to the script with the value either "foo" or "fum".

If I get the value "foo" I want the result to be "file1.txt file2.txt", and "file1.txt file3.txt" if the value is "fum", i.e. if I receive foo eclude files in subdirectory "fum" and vice versa

Comment: Does it have to be regex? If not, a two-liner should do the job: `find . -name "file*.txt"; find ${1} -name "file*.txt" | cut -d/ -f2;` - where ${1} is the received value.

Comment: use the `-wholename` flag instead?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

In case of search for foo, exlude fum

```
find . -name "file*.txt" | grep -vP "\/fum\/"
```